# Separate text from URL in Excel column

Tags: python, excel, libreoffice-calc

What I have is a column in Excel with a list of URLs like this:

- [first link](http://www.example.com/1)
- [second link](http://www.example.com/2)
- ...

What I would like is to separate the "text" from the "URL" like this:

- first link | http://www.example.com/1
- second link | http://www.example.com/2
- ...

I'm using LibreOffice, but I'd accept and answer also for Google Spreadsheet or even a python script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three steps simple solution (for Google Sheets):

- just copy and '*paste values only*' to get the text (or use concatenate-with-nothing)
- check this [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89557/extract-the-link-text-and-url-from-a-hyperlinked-cell) for a custom function to get the url
- concatenate text and url.